# playground message "number of times"

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift-playground

I was playing in swift playground. I get a funny message on the right side of the screen (10 times) and have trouble determining the meaning of it. it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Did you call that method from anywhere in your playground ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That message describes how many times that specific line/block of code was run on a single execution of the playground's simulator, which runs constantly in the background.

Answer (score 1):

It indicate for loop iterations. you can check actual output in console by view->Show Assistant Editor->Show Assistant Editor.loops iteration appear printed as shown in Image

[image]